# Importar Excel Laravel maatwebsite3.1

Tags: laravel-5, excel, laravel-excel, maatwebsite

estoy realizando un sistema para importar excel a mi BD con maatwebsite 3.1 pero el ToModel no lo encuentra, Alguien sabe porque pasa eso? Gracias de ante mano[image]

Answer (score 0):

intente utilizar la siguiente función si le permite leer los datos

yo tengo la siguiente versión en mi proyecto en composer.json, este si me funciona a mi,    "maatwebsite/excel": "^2.1", no se le funcione con la versión 3

```
'providers' => [
     Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
]
'aliases' => [
    'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
]
```

//librería

```
use \Excel;


ini_set('max_execution_time', 1640); //240 segundos = 4 minutos
        Excel::load('public/excel/Inventario_alcaldia.xlsx', function ($archivo) {
            $result = $archivo->get();
            //var_dump($result);
            foreach ($result as $key => $value) {

                echo $value->codigodeid . ' <br>';
                echo $value->codigodeid . ' <br>';
                echo $value->codigodeid . ' <br>'; 
            }
        })->get();
```

si no puede puede mirar este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_AhZ2j5sI8